# Online transcription service of a voice memo

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web app which creates a transcription of a voice memo?

Answer (score 1):

If you reside in the US you can use [Google Voice](http://www.google.com/googlevoice/about.html) which seems pretty good for this case. The only idea I have to use it, is calling  your own number and playing the file. Ok, it not really a web app if you use it like this.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[Jott](http://jott.com) offer such a service.</strike>

Jott has now [been shutdown](http://jott.com), however they do suggest the following similar services:

> **Looking for a service like Jott?**
>
> - [Dragon Dictation](http://www.dragonmobileapps.com/apple/dictation.html) for iPhone, iPad and iPod touch from Nuance lets you to speak text for emails, text messages, status updates and
>     more, and see your text appear instantly.
> - [Dragon for E-Mail](http://www.dragonmobileapps.com/bb/dragonforemail.html) for BlackBerry from Nuance lets you speak text for your emails, including the contact details in the ‘To' lines,
>     the subject and the body.
> - [FlexT9](http://www.dragonmobileapps.com/android/flex.html) for Android from Nuance is a unique four-in-one keypad app that lets you Speak, Trace, Write or Tap your text for emails,
>     text messages, web searches – anywhere you input text.

Answer (score 0):

[Voice2Note](http://voice2note.dial2do.com/):

> Record voice notes as usual using your favourite Evernote app
> on your Smartphone, PC or browser. Or for totally handsfree voice notes, we'll
> give you a special phone number to dial and speak your note using ANY phone.